# How can I use su again after OTA-upgrading my rooted phone?

Tags: rooting, adb

I had previously rooted my droid when it was running 2.2 froyo. Using the OTA upgrade, i got a gingerbread (2.3.4) for my phone. As obvious, the root privileges were gone..but the superuser app and the everything else related to it is still there in the system/bin and system/xbin folders. Now when i try to run "su" command from an adb shell to re-root my phone, it shows "permission denied".

Is there anyway that i can get the "#" shell i.e. the su privileges instead of the normal "$" shell, so that i can manually delete the previous root files?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you install any custom recovery, such as ClockworkMod (CWM)? And do you have the Android SDK installed on your workstation?

Comment: no..CWM is not installed..While I have android sdk installed with me.

Comment: I doubt you get root access directly, but you could try to `adb shell` and see whether you get a `#` (root) prompt or a `$` (user) prompt. In the latter case, you could try to `sudo` and see whether that works. Unlikely, but possible. With CWM, you could have connected `adb shell` in recovery mode with root permissions, AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the OTA upgrade clobbered your root settings, am afraid to say you will have to run either [SuperOneClick](http://shortfuse.org/) or [zergRush](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1296916) to get root again.

[**TECHNICAL**]

The OTA reverted the original `default.prop` when on Froyo from this

```
ro.secure=0
```

to this after the upgrade

```
ro.secure=1
```

Thus you may still have the `su` binary etc, but it is the above line that is preventing you from trying to switch user to id of 0 (that's what su stands for! - **S** witch **U** ser)

Comment: Is there a way I can manually change the value of this variable "ro.secure" to 0 ? using adb shell or something..keeping in mind that i cant access the root privileges right now?

Comment: zergRush was showing the message "hellions with blue flames". So I guess it wont work here.